# Why does cobra autocomplete isn't working?

Tags: macos, autocomplete, go-cobra

I have the following cobra cli example and I'm trying to make autocomplete to work on my mac.
https://github.com/dharmeshkakadia/cobra-example

If i compile it to a binary called "say" autocomplete work if i'll compile it to any other name it won't work
Is there some mac policy for it ?
My macos version is Big Sur 11.6

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The autocompletion is tied to the name of the command.

This correlates to the root command's name, which has to be the same as the built binary file name.

Cobra calculates a command's name by taking the first whitespace-delimited substring of the `cobra.Command`'s `.Use` field.

```golang
var rootCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "say", // must compile as 'say' to get completion to work
    Short: "My CLI",
}
```

```golang
var rootCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "othername", // must compile as 'othername' to get completion to work
    Short: "My CLI",
}
```

And no, this is not related to your Mac version. It it however related to which shell you're using. Given your Mac version, I'd guess the default shell is Z-Shell (a.k.a "zsh"). This binary file name restriction I mentioned above surely applies to zsh.